# Fourier transform of $f(t)\cos(at)$ given fourier transform of $f(t)$

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

When the fourier transform of $f(t)$ is $F(w)$, how can I find the fourier transform of $f(t)\cos(at)$?

Do I need to use some of fourier transform properties?

Comment: * is convolution? Then [use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) $\mathcal{F}[f*g] = \mathcal{F}[f] \cdot \mathcal{F}[g]$

Comment: no,its multiplication

Comment: Then use the definition of the fourier transform, for example $G[w] = \int f(t)\cos(at) e^{iwt}{\rm d}t$, and write $\cos(at) = \frac{e^{iat}+e^{-iat}}{2}$ and try to write it in terms of the fourier transform of $f$. You will get a simple result.

Comment: No, use the reverse convolution theorem...